# Is is possible to "autoConfig" gRPC services in Java Dropwizard?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, grpc, dropwizard, dropwizard-guice

I'm looking for something similar to the `GuiceBundle.enableAutoConfig(MyResource.class)` type of functionality but for a gRPC server. EnableAutoConfig will scan through packages and register the resources as jersey components.

Is there a lib out there that will scan through packages and register resources as gRPC services? Trying to avoid manual instantiation of dependency injected/provided components.

Comment: Did you check this out https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter?

Comment: not sure, but I doubt as the API requires to pass service instances when building a server. Therefore, if there was a function like `enableAutoConfig(MyGrpcService.class)` it would also need to get all config params to build a server (port, connection recycling etc), which may be variable depending on the specific subclass of `ServerBuilder` that you are using. I always just create my service instances with `Guice.getInstance(MyService.class)` and pass them to a `ServerBuilder`.